# Query for Custom Post Type UI Does Not Loop All the Post

Tags: query

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'lirik_melayu',
    'orderby'  => array( 
            'ID' => 'DESC' ,
        ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$query_contents=Array();
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    array_push($query_contents,Array(
        "id"=>get_the_ID(),
        "title"=>get_the_title(),
        "url"=>get_permalink(),
    ));
    echo get_the_title()."<br />";
}
```

It will loop until Ten post only..

It should be 14 post! Why it loops until TEN ONLY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer..

Add `posts_per_page` in the arguments as `-1`.

It should look like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'lirik_melayu',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,   // set the limit post to UNLIMITED (-1 is unlimited)
    'orderby'  => array( 
            'ID' => 'DESC' ,
        ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$query_contents=Array();
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    array_push($query_contents,Array(
        "id"=>get_the_ID(),
        "title"=>get_the_title(),
        "url"=>get_permalink(),
    ));
    echo get_the_title()."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Yes, the `posts_per_page` argument must be set to `-1` to result in ALL posts available.